# Can't install ncurses on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, ncurses

I'm trying to install ncurses on my Ubuntu for 1 hour and I don't find any issue...

> **sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev**
>
> Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
>   Construction de l'arbre des dépendances
>   Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
>   Le paquet « mono-roslyn » n'est pas installé, et ne peut donc être supprimé
>   Vous pouvez lancer « apt-get -f install » pour corriger ces problèmes :
>   Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
>    mono-devel : Dépend: mono-roslyn (= 5.4.1.7-0xamarin1+ubuntu1604b1) mais ne sera pas installé
>                 Dépend: ca-certificates-mono (= 5.4.1.7-0xamarin1+ubuntu1604b1) mais 5.4.0.201-0xamarin10+ubuntu1604b1 devra être installé
>   E: Dépendances non satisfaites. Essayez « apt-get -f install » sans paquet
>   (ou indiquez une solution).

I've already try to update, upgrade, dist-upgrade, remove, clean, etc...

What can I do?

Thanks guys !

Comment: You should probably ask this over at [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) instead :)

Comment: try running `sudo apt -f install`

Comment: @JoshKisb already did it :(

Comment: Yes i'll we do it if nobody can answer :( @Olian04